# How to check if the state.highstate is applied on a minion?

Tags: python, salt-stack

How can I tell if the state.highstate is applied to a minion? Is there a salt-call i can make to see if salt.hightstate is applied?

---

I found out how... turns out lookup_jid returns a result for each state of True or False which is exactly what I was looking for.

bash

```
[root@localhost ~]# salt-run jobs.lookup_jid 20141105195906794185
10.0.2.15:
    ----------
    pkg_|-apache_|-httpd_|-installed:
        ----------
        __run_num__:
            0
        changes:
            ----------
        comment:
            Package httpd is already installed.
        duration:
            1671.884
        name:
            httpd
        result:
            True
        retcode:
            1
        start_time:
            20:16:06.942403
    service_|-apache_|-httpd_|-running:
        ----------
        __run_num__:
            1
        changes:
            ----------
        comment:
            Service httpd is already disabled, and is in the desired state
        duration:
            653.679
        name:
            httpd
        result:
            True
        retcode:
            1
        start_time:
            20:16:08.614446
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call `state.highstate` with `test=True`:

```
salt '*' state.highstate test=True
```

Comment: I don't feel like this is the correct solution because of: http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/writing.html#test-state. Specifically- "This will return data about what changes would occur if the state were actually run." its not actually applied.

Comment: Exactly, so when that reports 0 states to be run, it means the minion is already in highstate